# Is the “probability storm” concept that split Scott and Hope into multiple versions adapted from the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, adaptation-comparison, ant-man-and-the-wasp-quantumania

Scott Lang and Hope van Dyne face a strange phenomenon in *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*: a “**probability storm**” that splits them into multiple versions (“possibilities”) of themselves based on “every choice they could make”. This leads to some hilarious bickering among the Scott Langs, but they also work together to overcome the probability storm.

[image: GIF of "probability storm" scene]
[image: GIF of probability storm scene]

I’m curious if this concept of a “probability storm” is original to the film or if it was adapted from the comics. If it's the latter, which comic book originally introduced it?

Comment: The more I watch the gif and the more I feel like he gets turned into spaghetti.

Comment: @Clockwork Spaghettification seems to be a common theme in the MCU. First, Reed Richards in the *Multiverse of Madness*, then Ant-Man in *Quantumania*, and then the recent events in *Loki*…

Answer (score 5):

Well, something similar happened in [Fantastic Four #337](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_337) (Feb, 1990) by Walter Simonson (the creator of the Time Variance Authority) et all

[image: Cover from FF 337]

[image: FF337 scene]

Comment: Fascinating. And it looks like Kang the Conqueror has a hand in this as well.